# Jenkins won't compile C program on WSL

Tags: jenkins, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just started learning how Jenkins works and at this moment I'm trying to build a Jenkins Pipeline Job on a **WSL2 Ubuntu** that automatically compiles my program `main.c` and runs it using `./a.out` command.

This is my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                cd /mnt/e/dev/jenkins
                gcc -Wall main.c
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                ./a.out
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my `main.c` is stored inside the `E:\dev\jenkins` Windows directory, and before compiling it, I'll need to `cd` into that directory. After compilation, being in the same directory, I'm trying to run the program, through the `Test` stage.

The problem is, whenever I click on "Build now", my builds fail, outputting an error like this:

```
Started by user Mario Mateaș
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: expecting '}', found 'main' @ line 8, column 27.
                   gcc -Wall main.c
                             ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:349)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:966)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:334)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:440)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Also, if needed, that's how my `main.c` looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open specified file.\n");
        return -2;
    }

    char buff[100];

    while (!feof(f)) {
        fgets(buff, 100, f);
        printf("%s\n", buff);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What can be the problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Pretty sure you need to wrap your commands [inside a shell step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#linux-bsd-and-mac-os) ... `sh 'my_cmd params'`. You can use [pipeline: Basic steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) directly, for example `dir path` instead of shell steps, if installed.

Comment: @IanW Great, but when I now try to build the job, I receive an error when trying to compile my `main.c`: ```+ gcc -Wall main.c
gcc: error: main.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.```

Comment: @IanW Using only shell commands (without any Jenkinsfile) works. `main.c` is in `/dev/jenkins`.

Comment: You could try using a shell step block - 3 backtick. But a pipeline will typically execute in a workspace on an agent (typ. has workspace in the path); not sure what's in or where "/mnt/e/dev/jenkins". Maybe have an "env" and "ls" and see where / what's there.

Comment: @IanW `ls` doesn't output anything. Don't I need to mention somewhere in my `Jenkinsfile` that I'm using Linux, and not Windows?

Comment: @IanW `/mnt/e/dev/jenkins/` is the Windows equivalent to `E:\dev\jenkins` in WSL

Comment: Figured it was WSL. If using Basic Steps, those are portable, I believe. If using Windows, then it would be [`bat`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script) or [`powershell/pwsh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-windows-powershell-script). `ls`  shows nothing in dir or error? Try `pwd` and confirm where you are.

Comment: @IanW It seems that `ls` doesn't output anything, but when I `pwd`, it outputs `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CTest`. `pwd`-ing again, after navigating to the folder with `cd`, the output is the same (`/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CTest`). Using cd by hand in my terminal works, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240595/discussion-between-mario-matea-and-ian-w).